# sys config SMO and DMO XPs automatic most duration query

Tags: sql-server, database, config

This is the second query with the highest duration value on the activity monitor in the SQL Server database, half an hour and 1 hour later, this query does not exist at the moment, but it came instantaneously.

The value here defaults to 1 and that's okay, and how did this query come by itself without any extra action?

Does anyone know, have seen a similar query?

```
SELECT se.is_admin_endpoint AS AdminConnection,
       (SELECT CAST(cfg.value AS bit) AS [ConfigValue]
        FROM sys.configurations cfg
        WHERE configuration_id = 16387) AS SmoEnabled
FROM sys.endpoints se
     INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections dmc ON dmc.endpoint_id = se.endpoint_id
WHERE dmc.session_id = @@spid;
```